# Google Maps markers with directions renderer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So I want to plot a route using directions renderer and at the same time have Origin as an "A" marker, all the way through the destination as the final marker, with all waypoints also being marker.

By default it looks like renderer only sets markers for origin and destination, so I plotted markers for all the waypoints.

However, the directionsrenderer markers are "A" for origin and "B" for destination, meanwhile my second waypoint is also "B".

How do I get all the waypoints on chronological order of the route to show the correct marker with correct letter? Here's an image of the problem:

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inspect `DirectionsRoute.waypoint_order` to get an array of which order the waypoints are ordered in.  Then I'd say use that to work out which letters to assign to each waypoint marker